# I can't add pictures to project on Android Studio

Tags: android

For some strange reason on Android Studio I just can't figure out why I can't import images to the drawable folder or any folder on the project. I keep getting "**Refracting cannot be performed**" error but not sure why.

[image]

I never had this problem before, it just came out of the blue. No matter what picture I add, I just keep getting this message.

Comment: run your Android Studio as administrator

Comment: One temporarily solution I did was to close the project and copy the images to the drawable folders where my project is located at, then I opened the project and the images showed up fine. It's not really a solution but it works for now.

Comment: please refer [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx)

Comment: With administrator I can't even drop the images at all

Comment: aah, i see now. Hmm but it looks like a permission issue to me.

Comment: I never used to run Android Studio as admin and I didn't make any recent changes for the user permissions. In a way I am happy that I found a work around it but its really not the true solution.